# Get specific letters from a string

Tags: python, delimiter

My input is a variable is a string:

```
 entity = "SmartSys_1_13_PP"
```

I need to extra the last two letters of the name of the entity. The results would be PP in this case.

One possible solution is to delimit the name using the _ and then consider the last field as the answer. Is there a one line which can directly parse the last two letters?

Comment: Something like `name[-2:]`?

Comment: is the pattern fixed?

Comment: The last two characters? `entity[-2:]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You my use string slicing. For your case, it will be: `name[-2:]`

But do not forget to add check, because it will return the string as it is in case length of string is less than 2. Your code should be like:

```
if len(name) > 2:
    print name[-2:]
else:
    # Whatever you want to do

### For example:
>>> '12345'[-2:]
'45'
>>> '1'[-2:]
'1'
>>> ''[-2:]
''
```

Comment: There won't be an exception if the string is less than two characters long.  You'll simply get the whole string in that case.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Update the answer. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

[Python strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) are sequences of individual characters. You can slice them the same way you would slice a Python list.

```
entity = 'SmartSys_1_13_PP'
print(entity[-2:])
PP
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, you can split the string on '_' then get the last substring:

```
>>> entity = "SmartSys_1_13_PP"
>>> entity.split('_')[-1]
'PP'
```